# How to merged two htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I have created two pages category.html and store-detail.html . I created each page in separated .htaccess file  page is working fine but how to merge two .htaccess file in single file.

category.html (.htaccess)

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/category\.html\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /category/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)$ /category.html?id=$1 [L]
```

store-detail.html (.htaccess)

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/store-detail\.html\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /store-detail/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^store-detail/([0-9]+)$ /store-detail.html?id=$1 [L]
```

Merged .htaccess file

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/category\.html\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/store-detail\.html\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /category/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^ /store-detail/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)$ /category.html?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^store-detail/([0-9]+)$ /store-detail.html?id=$1 [L]
```

I have created two dynamic pages category.html and store-detail.html, I am getting current URL this  http://localhost/category/?id=10 and http://localhost/store-detail/?id=10 working fine, But I am changing URL structure of http://localhost/category/10 and http://localhost/store-detail/200. If I run category.html hide store-detail page line in htaccess and If I run store-detail.html hide category access line. How to Merge?

See below file:
Now currently working store-detail page

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "/section.php?id=xxx" to "/section/xxx"
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/category\.html\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/store-detail\.html\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ /category/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ /store-detail/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite "/section/xxx" to "/section.php?id=xxx"
# RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)$ /category.html?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^store-detail/([0-9]+)$ /store-detail.html?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? And how is this related to Javascript or HTML?

Comment: How to merged category htaccess and store-detail htaccess file in single file.

Comment: Could you please help me.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What did you try? What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: Hi Nico added my question above could you please check and let me know. Thanks